# Use Grid View in List View React Native

Tags: listview, react-native, gridview, react-native-flatlist

I need to use List view and related images in grid view but nothing help my code is below please check and let me know if any help.

This is my array:

```
render() {
    var standardDataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1,r2) => r1 !== r2});
    var catArray = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "cat1",
        images: [
          {
            image:"https://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/41-Cute-And-Chic-Cornrow-Braids-Hairstyles.jpg",
          }
        ]
      }
]
```

Here is my view where I need to use show List view in Grid view.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
          <ListView style={styles.catsList}
            dataSource = {cloneCatArray}
            renderRow = {
              (rowData) =>
              <View>
                <Text style={styles.catsTitle}>{rowData.title}</Text>
                <Image style={{ height: 150, width:equalWidth }}
                source={{ uri: rowData.images[0].image }}
                resizeMode='cover'/>
              </View>
            }
          >
            /*<FlatList
              data= {cloneCatArray}
              numColumns = {4}
              renderItem={this.renderRowitem}
            />*/
          </ListView>
        </View>
```

[image]

This is the list what I need to preview with this:

```
1)Category1 (Hair)
a)image b) image c) image

2) Category 2 (Face)
a) image b) image c) image

3) Category 3 (Nails)
a) Image b) image c) image
```

Comment: why you don't use Flatlist ?

Comment: I am new in react native and I get good example with Listview so I used this... may you please share how to use flat list for this screen..Thanks!

Comment: I tried something like parent list view for category lists and as child FlatList for every category images.

Comment: you want just show the hair styles in grid view ?

Comment: I just update my question please check below what list I need to use here is category and every category have images so I am using List View for categories and FlatList for their images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your explanation in comment I recommend you to use cobination of scrollview and Flatlist, if you want to have grid view you can define numColumns for Flatlist, if you need to show the images horizontally you can define horizontal={true} in flatlist and remove the numColumns :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, FlatList, ScrollView ,Image} from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            categories: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    title: "cat1",
                    images: [
                        {
                            image: "https://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/41-Cute-And-Chic-Cornrow-Braids-Hairstyles.jpg",
                        },
                        {
                            image: "https://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/41-Cute-And-Chic-Cornrow-Braids-Hairstyles.jpg",
                        },
                        {
                            image: "https://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/41-Cute-And-Chic-Cornrow-Braids-Hairstyles.jpg",
                        },
                        {
                            image: "https://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/41-Cute-And-Chic-Cornrow-Braids-Hairstyles.jpg",
                        },
                        {
                            image: "https://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/41-Cute-And-Chic-Cornrow-Braids-Hairstyles.jpg",
                        },{
                            image: "https://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/41-Cute-And-Chic-Cornrow-Braids-Hairstyles.jpg",
                        },
                        {
                            image: "https://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/41-Cute-And-Chic-Cornrow-Braids-Hairstyles.jpg",
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    title: "cat2",
                    images: [
                        {
                            image: "https://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/41-Cute-And-Chic-Cornrow-Braids-Hairstyles.jpg",
                        },
                        {
                            image: "https://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/41-Cute-And-Chic-Cornrow-Braids-Hairstyles.jpg",
                        },
                        {
                            image: "https://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/41-Cute-And-Chic-Cornrow-Braids-Hairstyles.jpg",
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    title: "cat3",
                    images: [
                        {
                            image: "https://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/41-Cute-And-Chic-Cornrow-Braids-Hairstyles.jpg",
                        },
                        {
                            image: "https://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/41-Cute-And-Chic-Cornrow-Braids-Hairstyles.jpg",
                        },
                        {
                            image: "https://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/41-Cute-And-Chic-Cornrow-Braids-Hairstyles.jpg",
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
   
    _renderItem = ({item}) => (
        <Image style={{width:100,height:100}}  source={{uri : item.image}}/>
      );

    _keyExtractor = (item, index) => index;
      
    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1}}>
                {this.state.categories.map((cat, index) => {
                    return (
                        <View key={cat.id}>
                        <Text>{cat.title}</Text>
                        <FlatList
                            data={cat.images}
                            numColumns={3}
                            extraData={cat.images}
                            keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                            renderItem={this._renderItem}
                        />
                        </View>
                    )
                })}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```